# Embedding username in C++ application to make logins easier?

Tags: c++, security, authentication, piracy-protection

Protecting against piracy when developing desktop applications through product keys, obfuscation, or similar client-side protections is pointless (plenty of stackoverflow posts regarding that). The only real way to prevent piracy is to create a client-server communication where important code is only on the server.

That's what I'm attempting to do with my software, require a login in order to authenticate requests to the server to process some data. Throw in an easy way to change the password and IP session tracking and it's pretty foolproof. However, now the user must enter a username and password when they want to use it, and they could enter someone else's credentials very easily.

Then thought then crossed my mind, what about embedding the username within the application when a user downloads the client software? Only a password would be required from the user's point of view, speeds things up a bit. Yes it's still possible to edit the program to someone else's username, but now it's less obvious.

---

So that's my question, are there any security risks or design flaws with having the username hard coded into the program? And secondly, how does one begin to implement the username embedding and C++ compilation on say... a Node js server application?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: i dont really understand your motivation. You'd still have to make sure that the username is unique and you'd still have no guarantee that someone trying to connect with some username really is that user

Comment: What about having the program generate/have stored in it a unique serial number that the user registers against.  Then you can control which users can log into which serial number.  Then you can even allow the software to be installed on multiple machines and you just don't allow concurrent access or only N concurrent accesses.

Comment: The username would be unique. Like any other username and login authentication. I'm just proposing embedding the username within their copy of the application when a new user makes an account. 1 less step for login and reduces the chance of using someone else's credentials. Pair that with password changing by entering the old password and IP tracking and it reduces concurrent sessions. Doesn't eliminate I know... it would be like Netflix.

Comment: @NathanOliver Could the username serve as the serial number?

Comment: @mrg95 It also removes the ability for someone to legitimately login from somebody else's computer, which is fairly common in an office setting.

Comment: It could.  I offered the serial number approach so your end users could chose their own user name and allow for multi-access.

Comment: @MichaelSurette Yep, which is sort of the idea since this definitely isn't an office setting. The user could still move the entire application to another computer (or redownload from the server) and it would still work. The idea is to require a login on a website in order to download the application which has their username embedded. Sound like a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the point of server-hosted software, and that's this:

**You always have control over the server. You never have control over the client**.

So when you say:

> the user must enter a username and password when they want to use it, and they could enter someone else's credentials very easily

What you really mean is:

> When someone enters someone else's credentials what can I do?

The answer to that is to limit or cancel access for credentials depending on access patterns. If you see suspicious access, like coming from IPs in different countries, you may want to investigate and possibly ban the account.

You're not powerless here when you control the server. Lock people out if you must.

You also don't want to embed information in the executable because legitimate owners, your customers, will want to verify they downloaded the right file based on a cryptographic hash like SHA2. If you modify each file they can't do this, and every version looks "hacked".

Instead, if you must, create some kind of encrypted access or license file that can be supplied to the server and decrypted with a key that's only stored on the server. Sure, they can share that file with someone else, but you can identify the unauthorized access and handle it accordingly.

Comment: Okay thanks a ton for the info! When you talk about encrypted access or a license file, is that basically a token (JWT)? The user would still need to log in correct?

Comment: It's whatever you want it to be, so if that works for you that's one option. If you want to prevent user modifications then encrypting it with a secret key only you have is best.

Comment: I'm mainly wanting to limit user interaction. If they never need to sign in, just have a token that i can track via IP, then i'd do it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can only revoke tokens through a blacklist right? any better ways?

Comment: That's usually how it's done. What else would you do when someone obviously pirates your software? You'll want to be sure to dial in the sensitivity on your banning as you don't want to kick someone for using a VPN and having their IP flop around a lot, or because they rotate and work from different coffee shops.

Comment: Well I was planning on putting an expiration date on the tokens and then require a log in every so often. Then if a log in happens from another IP, then I would log out everyone else. Persistent tokens makes that difficult. But if I can do away with logins and still have that control over the tokens then I would like to know.

Comment: At this point my advice is to look at how other applications do it and evaluate if their approach would work for you. Consider Adobe Creative Suite, Steam, Microsoft Office, etc.